# Proof of Euclid's Lemma through contradiction

Tags: proof-verification

I tried to prove Euclid's Lemma. Please tell me if it's correct, I'm new to proofs.

Euclid's Lemma: Let $p$ be a prime number and $a$ and $b$ be natural numbers greater than 1, then if $p|ab$ we know $p|a$ or  $p|b$

I rewrote this as:
$[p$ prime $\land$ $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{N}, a,b \gt 1] \Rightarrow [ p|ab \Rightarrow (p|a \lor  p|b)]$

Proof by contradiction.

Suppose the antecedent is true and the consequence is false. That is
$[p|ab \land p|a \land p|b] (*)$ is true.

Then $b=pc$ and $a=pd$ and $ab=p^2cd$. In this case $cd$ must also necessarily be divisible by $p$ since $p$ is prime. In this case $a$ and $b$ can only be multiples of $p$ for $(*)$ to hold true. But this is in contradiction with the antecedent that $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{N}, a,b \gt 1$.

Comment: I don't exactly follow why $cd$ must be divisible by $p$.

Comment: because p is prime and the only divisors of a prime number is 1 or itself

Comment: Could we not have $b = p$ and $a = p$ and then $c = d = 1$. In which case $p \nmid cd$.

Comment: if $c=d=1$ it still holds true that there is contradiction, I guess, as I said I'm new to this

Answer (score 0):

**(1)Try to focus on the most essential things first:**
       $p|ab \to p|a \lor p|b$
and only then on quantifiers:
       $\forall prime\ p \land \forall a,b \in \mathbb N$
Now combine:
$$\forall prime\ p: \forall a,b \in \mathbb N:p|ab \to p|a \lor p|b$$

I'll prove this lemma by contradiction for $\forall a,b \in \mathbb N$
Suppose the claim is wrong, then:(we negate lemma)
if we rewrite implication $x \to y\ as\ \neg x \lor y $, then its negation would be: $x \land \neg y$
**(2)You should negate the whole statement at once**
Negation of original claim is:
$$\exists prime\ p: \exists a,b \in \mathbb N: p|ab \land \neg(p|a \lor p|b)$$
$$\exists prime\ p: \exists a,b \in \mathbb N: p|ab \land (p \nmid a) \land (p \nmid b)$$
**(3)now we have to get the contradiction combining all the constituent parts of the line above, and everything what had led us to that line above.**
Now we'll use the division theorem and get a contradiction.
$p \nmid b$ means $b=n_1p+r_1, 1 \le r_1 <p$
same for $p \nmid a$:
$p \nmid a$ means $a=n_2p+r_2, 1 \le r_2 <p$
now $ab = (n_2p+r_2)(n_1p+r_1)$
$p|ab$ so $ab=n_3p$, combine this with prev line:
$ab = (n_2p+r_2)(n_1p+r_1) = n_3p$
because $r_1 <p$ and $r_2 < p$, there's no way we get multiple of p to the left$\square$